# nginx, exchange and ntlm

Tags: nginx, exchange-server, ntlm

I read many things about using nginx with exchange and NTLM (really many !!). I saw all and the opposite! Often people told it is working, but then said later only with basic auth. Very hard to find a real reply...

Problem is becoming more important now that Outlook 2016 only works in Outlook anywhere mode that needs NTLM (yes I can change it to basic auth, but then user will have to always enter password.)

I can read thinks like:

```
upstream http_backend {
    server 1.1.1.1:80;

    keepalive 16;
}

server {
...

location / {
       proxy_pass http://http_backend/;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Connection "";
    ...
    }
 }
```

That sounds great, but on nginx forum they told me it won't work except if I have exactly one user!
https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,72871,264560#msg-264560

I seems I have to go with commercial version on nginx that supports NTLM.

Can somebody tells me if he already used free nginx with https to go on exchange server ? I'll have many exchange servers to address (it is working for the time being on OWA, as this is basic auth)

Or maybe you can advise me another free reverse proxy that will work with exchange ?

Thanks a lot, do not hesitate to ask me more info.